# Why does starting a Process make my C# console app so slow?

Tags: c#, adb

I have a C# console application that first initializes some controllers -> start a new process for ADB, forward a port and start an app with it -> then print out a menu that asks user for input:

```
// Initialize some controllers here
// Create a new process for ADB
...

// --- Start an app with ADB:
var appProcess = new Process();
var appInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
appInfo.FileName = ADB_PATH;
appInfo.Arguments = ... ; // arguments here
appInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
appInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
appProcess.StartInfo = appInfo;
appProcess.Start();

appProcess.OutputDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    // Do something with output data
};
appProcess.ErrorDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
   // Do something with eror data
};
appProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
appProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();
appProcess.Dispose();

// ----------------------------

while (keepAppRunning)
{
    // Print menu
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine()
}
```

That `Console.ReadLine()` is so slow. When I press some keys in the console, the keys do not appear right away. Typing has some very noticeable delay. I can't press Enter either. It slows other parts of my app too. I have to wait for like a minute before everything becomes responsive again.

I tried putting that starting app part in isolation and the problem persists so I'm convinced that the problem is somewhere in there.

Comment: Have you measured where the delay is? Have you considered offloading work to a background thread?

Answer (score 1):

You're initializing `appProcess` and `appInfo`, but then start `serverProcess`. Was this your intention, or did you mean to call `appProcess.Start()`?

Also, are you checking if `e.Data` is null in your callbacks? Those could be the choke point here, but hard to say with the code you've provided. Try putting a breakpoint (or at the very least, a `Debug.WriteLine(e.Data.ToString())`) in your "do something" code to see how often they're being invoked.

On a side note, I would suggest either putting this in a try/catch/finally (calling `appProcess.Dispose()` in your finally block), or using the `using(...)` statement, to ensure that resources are cleaned up if something throws (see the modified version of your code below).

Whatever the case, `Console.ReadLine` isn't the culprit. It's just where some other problem is manifesting itself (since that's the only user-facing point in the provided code).

```csharp
using var appProcess = new Process()
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = "", // filename here
        Arguments = "", // arguments here
        RedirectStandardError = true,
        RedirectStandardOutput = true
    }
};

appProcess.OutputDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        // Do something with output data, but only if it's not null
    }
};

appProcess.ErrorDataReceived += delegate (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Data != null)
    {
        // Do something with eror data, but only if it's not null
    }
};

appProcess.Start();
appProcess.BeginErrorReadLine();
appProcess.BeginOutputReadLine();

while (keepAppRunning)
{
    // Print menu
    string userInput = Console.ReadLine()
}
```

Comment: I did mean to call `appProcess.Start()` instead. My bad. I did do null checking for `e.Data`. If I comment out the delegates and stdout/stderr redirection, the lag still occurs.

Comment: And if you remove the code that prints your menu, does the lag still occur?

Comment: It does. I put that piece of code at the beginning of my `Main` method then a `ReadLine()` followed by a `Environment.Exit(0)`. The lag is still there. :(

Comment: Then it's most likely a byproduct of something originating from one of the processes you are starting. Use process of elimination to narrow it down to the offending process.

Comment: Wouldn't be surprised if it wasn't an overly-selfish loop in serverProcess; running it in it's own thread or asynchronously would probably fix it.

Comment: Thank you @Stelio, I found out the solution. For whatever reason, starting adb from the adb executable causes the app to be so slow. If I start a shell process, redirect stdin to a StreamWriter, and use that StreamWriter to call adb, it works fine.